# Full screen and close full screen In one button click

Tags: javascript

I have one button for full screen but I want both `full screen` and `close screen` in one button

Here is my code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {   
//Btn Full Screen
  $("#btnFullScreen").click(function () {
    alert("Test");
    var el = document.documentElement,
    rfs = el.requestFullscreen
      || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
      || el.mozRequestFullScreen
      || el.msRequestFullscreen
    ;
    rfs.call(el);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnFullScreen" name="btnFullScreen" value="Full Screen" />
</div>
```

Full screen working fine. But I want same event fire in same button but cannot figure out.

Comment: It works for me... what's your issue?

Comment: Yes also works for me ,my issue is am trying full screen and close in same button. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save current window state to the button attribute like the following:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  //Btn Full Screen
    $("#btnFullScreen").click(function () {
     if($(this).attr('data-fullscreen') === 'true') {
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
      } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }
      $(this).attr('data-fullscreen', '');
      $(this).attr('value', 'Full Screen');
    } else {
      var el = document.documentElement,
        rfs = el.requestFullscreen
          || el.webkitRequestFullScreen
          || el.mozRequestFullScreen
          || el.msRequestFullscreen
      ;
      rfs.call(el);
      $(this).attr('data-fullscreen', 'true');
      $(this).attr('value', 'Exit Fullscreen');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnFullScreen" name="btnFullScreen" value="Full Screen" />
</div>
```

Comment: What if I hit F11? Also you could `$(this).attr({prop:val, prop2:val})` ... jQuery stuff

Comment: There is not an easy solution to check whether browser is in fullscreen mode or not. You can bind keydown event for `F11`. I wanted to show him how to run conditional statements to one button event. This is not for downvoting for sure.